# gulp js concat issue

Tags: gulp, gulp-concat, gulp-uglify

```
/*global -$ */
'use strict';
var gulp = require('gulp');
var $ = require('gulp-load-plugins')();
var jshint = require('gulp-jshint');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var rename = require('gulp-rename');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var csso = require('gulp-csso');
var argv = require('yargs').argv;
var gulpif = require('gulp-if');
var inquirer = require('inquirer');
var minifyHTML = require('gulp-minify-html');
var browserSync = require('browser-sync');
var del = require('del');
var reload = browserSync.reload;

// variables
var production = !!(argv.production);  
var dev = !!(argv.dev);  
var move = !!(argv.move); 
var app = 'app';
var dist = 'dist';
var src = {
  scss : app+'/style.scss',  
  scripts:{
  modernizr:'bower_components/modernizr/modernizr.js',
  vendor:['bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js',
  'bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/assets/javascripts/bootstrap.js',
  ],
  main:app+'/scripts/main.js'
  }
};

// Vendor js
gulp.task('vendorScripts', function(){
  return gulp.src(src.scripts.vendor)
    .pipe(concat('vendor.js'))    
    .pipe(gulpif(dev,gulp.dest(app+'/js/vendor/')))
    .pipe(gulpif(production,gulp.dest(app+'/js/vendor/')))
    .pipe(rename('vendor.min.js'))
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(gulpif(dev,gulp.dest(app+'/js/vendor/')))
    .pipe(gulpif(production,gulp.dest(dist+'/js/vendor/')));
});
```

When I run gulp vendorScripts --production 
compile only vendor.min.js 
but When I run gulp vendorScripts  --dev
compile vendor.js and vendor.min.js

I want to be compile both file in dist folder.
What is the problem happened?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems you wanted to write `dist` for production, but u wrote `app`. change the second line to use dist rather than app.

```
.pipe(gulpif(dev,gulp.dest(app+'/js/vendor/')))
.pipe(gulpif(production,gulp.dest(app+'/js/vendor/')))
```

below it is correct

```
.pipe(gulpif(dev,gulp.dest(app+'/js/vendor/')))
.pipe(gulpif(production,gulp.dest(dist+'/js/vendor/')));
```

just an advice: rather than using gulp-if, apply js if-else logic to get the output dir name and use that in the task...